# Removing Proximity Alert doesn't work

Tags: android, proximitysensor

I have a problem with remove proximity alert, and for test I try to addProximityAlert and remove it immediately after.
I have this function:

```
public void addproximity(View v) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("proximityService", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int unique_id = sharedPref.getInt("PENDING_ID", 0);
    unique_id = unique_id+1;

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("PENDING_ID", unique_id);
    editor.commit();
    Intent intentNew = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    double latitude = 43.9297615;
    double longitude = 10.2035046;
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), unique_id, intentNew, 0);
    lm.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, 200, -1, pi);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
    mHandleMessageReceiver = new ProximityAlertReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, filter);


    lm.removeProximityAlert(pi);

}
```

But I tested with fake gps, and the proximity not deleted, and broadcast still receive event.
what I'm wrong?

Comment: But -1 why? can you explain me?

Answer (score 1):

in `addProximityAlert()` method you are passing -1 as expiration value,which means your geofrence will not expire (`Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE`).That's why geofrence is not removing.Change this flag and try again.

Comment: hello Jinesh, thankyou, yes I passed -1 because I want that proximity not expired after time, but I want delete it manually

Comment: call  lm.removeUpdates(pi) also.

Comment: my problem is more complex could you join to chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122743/proximity-alert-doesnt-work

Comment: I 'have resolved, the problem was action.
But I would like know why -3. When somone click -1 he should motivate.
Hovewer thank @Jinesh for help.